# Android color background OptionMenu

Tags: android, colors, background, toolbar

I want to change the background color of OptionMenu. I use the ToolBar and I created the Theme, but the background color of OptionMenu is not change. What is wrong?

The toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:popupTheme="@style/Toolbar_Popup"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
android:elevation="2dp"/>
```

styles

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>

</style>

<!-- PopUp theme. -->
<style name="Toolbar_Popup" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
</style></resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working well for mine.  Have you tried to clean and rebuild?

```
activity_main.xml
`    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.siwarak.toolbar.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:popupTheme="@style/Toolbar_Popup"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:elevation="2dp"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    `
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>



<!-- PopUp theme. -->
<style name="Toolbar_Popup" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```